# Exclude rows in one R data.table that are present in another on multiple keys

Tags: r, data.table

I have two R data.tables like so:

```
first

user_id | val
-------------
      1 |   A
      1 |   C
      2 |   A
      3 |   C
      4 |   B
      1 |   B
      2 |   C
      3 |   B
      1 |   D

second

user_id | val
-------------
      1 |   A
      1 |   C
      4 |   B
```

I want to get the rows in `first` that are not in `second` like so:

```
third

user_id | val
-------------
      2 |   A
      3 |   C
      1 |   B
      2 |   C
      3 |   B
      1 |   D
```

So I know about the `setdiff` function, and I know I can merge like so `first[!second,]`, but I don't know how to do it for the multiple key case.

Comment: Look into the `%in%` operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `on` parameter, assume `df1` and `df2` are both `data.table`s:

```
df1[!df2, on=.(user_id, val)]

#   user_id val
#1:       2   A
#2:       3   C
#3:       1   B
#4:       2   C
#5:       3   B
#6:       1   D
```

Comment: `on` could also just be `names(df1)`

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)

third <- first %>%
anti_join(second, by = c("user_id", "val"))
```

Comment: You should explain why this answers the OP's question.